# Inner join with index query MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

I have two tables

**Customers**

```
CustomerID   name  x2       x3 
--------------------------------
14tr          Joe   att2   att3
11ty          Jack  att2   att3
```

**Deposit**

```
Depositid CustomerID quantity date      att3 att4
--------------------------------------------------
13           14tr      100   12-12-12     5    6
14           14tr      200   12-13-12     8    1
15           14tr      140   12-16-12     9    6
16           11ty      10    12-19-12     1    6
17           11ty      20    12-19-12     1    1
18           11ty      114   12-21-12     1    6
```

I want the following result:

Result

```
No   name    quantity     date  att3 att4    x2     x3
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1    Joe       100   12-12-12     5    6    att2  att3
1    Joe       200   12-13-12     8    1    att2  att3  
1    Joe       140   12-16-12     9    6    att2  att3
2    Jack       10   12-19-12     1    6    att2  att3
2    Jack       20   12-19-12     1    1    att2  att3
2    Jack      114   12-21-12     1    6    att2  att3
```

To do so I am doing

```
SELECT
  b.name, 
  a.quantity, 
  a.date, 
  a.att3,
  a.att4, 
  b.x2, 
  b.x3
FROM
  Deposit a INNER JOIN Customer b
  ON a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID;
```

How can I get the No. column counter for each different customer like in the example?

Is there a better way to display the inner join between these two tables?

Comment: what version of ms access?

Comment: well is it possible to use Access 2007, and then 2010? or is it  a compatibility problem?

Comment: How can I get the No column?

Comment: it sound like you want to generate the `No.` column by sql, try this one http://www.ehow.com/how_5976723_do-number-records-access-query_.html

Comment: How would you do it in sql code? `DCount("id","myTable","id <= " & [id]) AS Counter`

Comment: Why is Joe numbered "1", and where do you expect that "1" to come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can :

```
SELECT DCount("*","Customer","CustomerID <='" & b.CustomerID & "'") AS Ct, 
b.name, 
a.quantity, 
a.Date, 
a.att3, 
a.att4, 
b.x2, 
b.x3
FROM Deposit AS a 
INNER JOIN Customer AS b ON a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
ORDER BY b.CustomerID;
```

Result:

```
Ct  name    quantity    Date    att3  att4  x2      x3
1   Jack    114     21/12/2012  1       6   att2    att3
1   Jack    20      19/12/2012  1       1   att2    att3
1   Jack    10      19/12/2012  1       6   att2    att3
2   Joe     140     16/12/2012  9       6   att2    att3
2   Joe     200     13/12/2012  8       1   att2    att3
2   Joe     100     12/12/2012  5       6   att2    att3
```

Comment: when I execute it, I am getting the counter set to 2 instead of 1, How can I set the counter to 1? , I used `SELECT DCount("*","Customer","CustomerID <= " & [b.CustomerID ])`

Comment: Oh, I changed it to `SELECT DCount("*","Customer","CustomerID < " & [b.CustomerID ])` and it worked

Comment: In that case, you must have a customer that is not appearing in your deposit table but does appear in your customer table. It would be best to create a query that gets a set of customers with deposits and use that for your DCount.